# ngRoute combined with react-router

Tags: reactjs, angularjs, react-router, ngroute, angularjs-ng-route

Is there a way to make `AngularJS’s ngRoute` work together with `react-router` ?

Main routing is inside the AngularJS application and I tried to add `react-router` for only a small part of the app but it seems to be conflicting with Angular’s routing. (navigating with `NavLink` works fine but going back in the browser seems to ignore everything `react-router` did).

I have been using `AngularJS 1.5.6 or 1.8.x` and `react-router v5.2.1`.

Below are some snippets for how the application is layered:

```
//inside Angular
.when("/newRoute", {
     // this is just a react component injected and rendered inside AngularJs
     template: ‘<div react-bridged-component data-component-name="RouteView"></div>’, 
})

//inside React
const RouteView = () => (
   <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
     <BrowserRouter basename="route">
       <SomeComponent />
     </BrowserRouter>
   </Suspense>
);
```

Comment: Need to find a way to sync their histories. We use ui-router with react-hybrid plugin, but it would be nice to start converting our react components to use react-router